# Using GWTP with Spring boot application

Tags: spring, gwtp

I have developed some RESTful web services in Sprint Boot (ver 1.2.3). Now, as part of same project, I want to develop a user interface using GWTP, consuming those web services. GWTP application will be deployed in the same embedded tomcat instance inwhich web services are deployed. Any idea, how should I continue further. Any pom.xml file for maven configuration will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, but instead of using embedded tomcat I'm using standalone container. I've created spring boot application using archetype. After that I've created GWTP skeleton project using GWTP plugin for eclipse. After that I've just copied all required stuff including maven dependencies into spring boot application.